# Extension method binding for explicit interface implementation

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

I have been playing with extension methods in order to add some capabilities to existing interfaces. When I implement interface members implicitly, compiler chooses the interface member implementation instead of extension method as it is stated in [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) MSDN page.

However, when I try explicit implementation, it seems that extension method is selected instead of implemented member of the interface.

```cs
//My interface and extension method for this interface
interface IExt
{
    void Extended(int e);
}

public static int Extended(this yapboz.IExt ext, int e)
{
    return e + 1;
}
```

When I implement the given Extended method explicitly (CExt below), it doesn't bind.

```cs
class CExt : IExt
{
    void IExt.Extended(int e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

After this implementation it returns integer value instead of throwing an exception!

However, when I implement the interface member implicitly (see below), then my code throws the exception.

```cs
class CExt : IExt
{
    public void Extended(int e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is never going to work.  The type resolver will use the method on your interface before it checks to see if an extention method even exists.  Remove the method from your interface.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I think the OP is talking about createing a `CExt` object and calling `Extended` on that which will call the extension method because the interface is explicitly implemented.

Comment: @MatthewWhited I wonder why implicit and explicit implementations have such a difference? For implicit case it is as I expected and calls the member method, but for the explicit case it prefers extension method?

Comment: If the interface has the same method as the extension method name the extension method will never be selected... unless you explicitly call it as a method on the static class and pass in the instance object.  If OP wants the ability to “override” the method from the class then again use the interface but don’t put a method.  If the method isn’t provided then the extension method will be used.  If it is provided then the local method will be used.

Comment: @Deniz An explicit implementation means you only see the implementation when referencing the object with the interface type.  So if you do `IExt e = new CExt(); e.Extended();`  It will call the implementation in `CExt` for the explicitly implemented method instead of the extension method because now the compiler will see the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicit implementations have to be called through the interface. So

```
IExt c = new CExt();
c.Extended(1);
```

will bind to the explicit interface implementaion since the variable is of the interface type,  but

```
CExt c = new CExt();
c.Extended(1);
```

Will bind to the extension method since there is no public `Extended` method on the `CExt` type itself.

So that's *why* it behaves the way it does.  However I would note that it's not a good idea to add extension methods that are the same as existing interface methods.  Extension methods are used to *extend* interfaces and classes, not to add an implementation to an existing interface method.